# C++ Access violation writing location in for loop

Tags: c++, directx

I was trying to make a Bounding Box work in order to implement frustrum culling in my engine. But as soon as i run the solution, an Access violation run time error appears in the transform function of the Bounding Box.

```
void BoundingBox::Transform(D3DXVECTOR3 pos, D3DXVECTOR3 rot, D3DXVECTOR3 sca) {

D3DXQUATERNION rotationQuaternion;

D3DXMatrixTransformation(&mat, NULL, NULL, &sca, NULL, 
    D3DXQuaternionRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotationQuaternion, 
    D3DXToRadian(rot.x), D3DXToRadian(rot.y), D3DXToRadian(rot.z)), &pos);

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        D3DXVec3Transform(&transVertex[k], &vertexes[k], &mat);

        /*this->*/xMin = min(transVertex->x, /*this->*/xMin);
        /*this->*/yMin = min(transVertex->y, /*this->*/yMin);
        /*this->*/zMin = min(transVertex->z, /*this->*/zMin);

        /*this->*/xMax = max(transVertex->x, /*this->*/xMax);
        /*this->*/yMax = max(transVertex->y, /*this->*/yMax);
        /*this->*/zMax = max(transVertex->z, /*this->*/zMax);
    }}
```

Anyone knows why this happens?

Here is what the error says: "Exception thrown at 0x0F5E20E6 (D3DX9_43.dll) in bushRanger.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000038."

Comment: And what does the debugger say? How do you even know this is the problematic routine? Run it under the debugger and it will show you which pointer you have failed to initialise.

Comment: From the near-zero address it looks like you might have a null `this` pointer.

Comment: Ken Y-N well, i ran the debugger and it stopped in the beggining of the for.

Comment: You need to compile with optimisation off. Also, did you check if any of the local variables or `this` were `NULL`?

Comment: Ken Y-N yes, `this` gives `null`, but why is that happening? the object should be initialized.

Comment: A [mcve] will likely be required for those of us out here to help you answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

I found what happened, the camera makes the frustrum but it doesn't have a bounding box, and it still uses the same Move() function as the rest of the composites.

```
    void Composite::Move(D3DXVECTOR3 trasl, D3DXVECTOR3 escal, D3DXVECTOR3 rot) 
{
Component::Move(trasl, escal, rot);
/*D3DXMATRIX rotMat = rotXMat * rotYMat * rotZMat;
thyMatrix = scaMat * rotMat * transMat;*/
D3DXQUATERNION rotationQuaternion;
D3DXMatrixTransformation(&thyMatrix, NULL, NULL, &escal, NULL, D3DXQuaternionRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotationQuaternion, D3DXToRadian(rot.x), D3DXToRadian(rot.y), D3DXToRadian(rot.z)), &trasl);
laCajita->Transform(_trasl, _escal, _rot); // and here is a non existant bounding box
UpdateBoundingBox();
}
```

Here when it touched the Move function of the Camera, who is a composite, it calls a non existant bounding box.

Well, people, thanks for the help in the comments, i will be more attentive with the debbugger from now on before posting a question.